# How to serialize only integer part of a node

Tags: c#, xml

```
<INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <RATE>12059.00/pcs</RATE>
   <AMOUNT>-6029500.00</AMOUNT>
   <ACTUALQTY> 500 pcs</ACTUALQTY>
   <BILLEDQTY> 500 pcs</BILLEDQTY>
</INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
```

here ACTUALQTY,RATE hass both integer and string part,I need only integer part,how can I do that

Comment: Please show us the code you use: XmlDoc, XDoc,...?

Comment: Write a custom serializer which is pretty easy as shown  [here](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/)

Comment: XmlNodeList stockitemnodes = voucharnode.SelectNodes("INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST");
                        foreach (XmlNode stocknode in stockitemnodes)
                        {
                            objpordetails.QUANTITY= Convert.ToDecimal(stocknode.SelectSingleNode("ACTUALQTY").InnerText);
                            objpordetails.RATE= Convert.ToDecimal(stocknode.SelectSingleNode("RATE").InnerText);
                        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you wanted to extract the decimal and integer part from the XML. So one of the solution could be

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("YourXMLFile");
var qty = xdoc.Descendants("ACTUALQTY").FirstOrDefault().Value;
string resultString = Regex.Match(qty, @"\d+").Value;
decimal actqty;
decimal.TryParse(resultString, out actqty);

var rt = xdoc.Descendants("RATE").FirstOrDefault().Value;
string resultRate = Regex.Match(rt, @"^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Value;
decimal actrt;
decimal.TryParse(resultRate, out actrt);
```

What I have tried with the solution is in `qty` we first get the value of `ACTUALQTY` which will be `500 pcs` then using Regex we only extracted the number part from the string and we get `500` then just used `decimal.TryParse` to convert it into decimal called `actqty` so you can assign `actqty` to `objpordetails.QUANTITY`

Now almost same concept is tried for `Rate` but since the value is `12059.00/pcs` and if we do the Regex using `"\d+"` we will only get `12059` and not the decimal part of it so a new regex i.e. `"^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"` is used to extract the decimal part of the string `12059.00/pcs` and it would become `12059.00` and then same way you can assign the value of `actrt` to `objpordetails.RATE`

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If the format of datas ar same you can use the below code

```
XElement xmlFileContent = XElement.Load("filePath");
        var datas=  xmlFileContent.Elements("INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST")
            .Select(i =>
            {
               return new
                {
                    Rate = i.Element("RATE").Value.Split('/')[0],
                    Actualqty = i.Element("ACTUALQTY").Value.Trim().Split(' ')[0]
                };
            }).ToList();
```

datas contain objects with Rate and Actualqty properties.